# JS without using Head (only Body)

Tags: jquery

I'm actually working on a CMS where I can't touch the Head, only insert content in the body, the JS Library is actually loaded though.

I tried to include the script from codrops in the `<script></script>` tags but didn't seem to work.

**The errors :**

> Uncaught ReferenceError: CBPFWTabs is not defined apercu-335.kjsp:1125
>   Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

**The code inside my `<body>` :**

```
<script>
    (function() {
            [].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( '.tabs' ) ).forEach( function( el ) {
                new CBPFWTabs( el );
            });

        })();
</script>

<script>
    ( function( window ) {
        'use strict';
    function extend( a, b ) {
        for( var key in b ) { 
            if( b.hasOwnProperty( key ) ) {
                a[key] = b[key];
            }
        }
        return a;
     }

    function CBPFWTabs( el, options ) {
        this.el = el;
        this.options = extend( {}, this.options );
        extend( this.options, options );
        this._init();
    }

    CBPFWTabs.prototype.options = {
        start : 0
    };

    CBPFWTabs.prototype._init = function() {
        // tabs elems
       this.tabs = [].slice.call( this.el.querySelectorAll( 'nav > ul > li' ) );
    // content items
    this.items = [].slice.call( this.el.querySelectorAll( '.content-wrap > section' ) );
    // current index
    this.current = -1;
    // show current content item
    this._show();
    // init events
    this._initEvents();
};

CBPFWTabs.prototype._initEvents = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.tabs.forEach( function( tab, idx ) {
        tab.addEventListener( 'click', function( ev ) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            self._show( idx );
        } );
    } );
};

CBPFWTabs.prototype._show = function( idx ) {
    if( this.current >= 0 ) {
        this.tabs[ this.current ].className = this.items[ this.current ].className = '';
    }
    // change current
    this.current = idx != undefined ? idx : this.options.start >= 0 &&     
this.options.start < this.items.length ? this.options.start : 0;
    this.tabs[ this.current ].className = 'tab-current';
    this.items[ this.current ].className = 'content-current';
    };

    // add to global namespace
    window.CBPFWTabs = CBPFWTabs;
})( window );</script>
```

**The source:** 
http://tympanus.net/codrops/

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Error `Unexpected end of input` means you have syntax errors in your code. Fix it.

*Side note*

You can include your code at the end of `<body>` as long as you don't use these functions anywhere before loading it.

*Will work:*

```
<script src="jquery"></script>
<script>$(document).ready();</script>
```

*Will not work:*

```
<script>$(document).ready();</script>
<script src="jquery"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I double checked the code and I think I do know now why.

Answer (score 0):

I have find the problem, thank everyone for your help.

The CMS displayed the code inline once the page saved, so after the first "//" in the code the next lines were treated as commentaries by the navigator.

I deleted all the comments from the code and It worked, the problem was not in the code but because a part of the code was not used.

Thank you and have a good day.